# elasticsearch n-gram example clarification

Tags: elasticsearch, n-gram

With reference to the example quoted here
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/ngrams-compound-words.html

looking for  "Adler" returns results.
A search for “Adler” becomes a query for the three terms adl, dle, and ler:

But why is the query for "Zdler" returning results even though zdl is not one of the terms ?

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "text": {
            "query": "zdler"
            }
          }
        }
}
```

Applying match query for search on "Adler" returns the record  -- expected.

However, match query on "Zdler" also returns  the record (because dle and ler match). Even setting "minimum_should_match": "100%" returns the record - not expected

Applying term query for search on "Adler" returns nothing -- not expected

```
POST /my_index/my_type/_search
    {
    "query": {
        "term": {
          "text": {
            "value": "Adler"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

How do I achieve returning the record only for search on "Adler" and not on "Zdler" ?

```
 "settings": {
  "index": {
    "number_of_shards": "5",
    "provided_name": "my_index",
    "creation_date": "1501069624443",
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "trigrams_filter": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": "3",
          "max_gram": "3"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "trigrams": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "trigrams_filter"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      }
    },
    "number_of_replicas": "1",
    "uuid": "Z5BXi_RjTACzTsR_-Nu9tw",
    "version": {
      "created": "5040099"
    }
  }
}
```

and these are the mappings

```
{
 "my_index": {
"mappings": {
  "my_type": {
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "trigrams"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Simply because `dle` and `ler` also match

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to apply standard analyser for search. 
below query returns a record and search for "zdler" will not return any result.

```
GET /my_index_2/my_type/_search
{
"query": {
    "match": {
        "text": {
            "query": "adler",
            "analyzer": "standard"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html) applies the field analyzer on the input query before throwing the query. this similarly produces tokens for input ("zdler") which are then matched again inverted index. But the same will not be the case with terms query as it doesn't apply field analyzer on input value

Match query breaks "adler" into -> "a", "d", "l", "e" ..... so on which are then matched against the inverted index.

Try to understand follow two queries

```
POST index5/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "zdler"
    }
  }
}


POST index5/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "text": {
        "value": "zdler"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added some more information to the question based on your answer.

Comment: also if you can add settings and mappings?

Comment: have added settings and mappings